# Application of Darboux's theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $f:[0,2] \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable with $f(0)=0,f(1)=2$, and $f(2)=1$. I must prove that there exists $c \in (0,2)$ such that $f'(c)=-\frac12$.

I have nearly completed the proof, but there is one claim which I am not certain I can make. For now, here is the proof:

We apply the Mean Value Theorem to obtain that there exists $c_1 \in (0,1)$ such that $f(1)-f(0)=f'(c_1)(1-0) \iff f'(c_1)=2$. We apply M.V.T. again to find that there exists $c_2 \in (1,2)$ such that $f(2)-f(1)=f'(c_2)(2-1) \iff f'(c_2)=-1$. This implies that $k=-\frac12$ is between $f'(0)$ and $f'(2)$, and hence, by Darboux's theorem, there exists $c \in (0,2)$ such that $f'(c)=-\frac12$.

My problem is with claiming that $k=-\frac12$ is between $f'(0)$ and $f'(2)$. I am not sure if this necessarily follows from the previous result. It would be fine if the question allowed $f$ to be continuously differentiable, but as it is, we can potentially have $f'$ to not be continuous for all $x \in [0,2]$. Is there any way I could fix/improve my proof, or is it fine as is? Thank you!

Comment: You have trouble claiming $-1/2$ is between $-1$ and $2$?

Comment: Note that $c_1<c_2$ and the interval $(c_1,c_2)$ is a subset of $(0,2)$. Because $-1/2$ is between $f'(c_2)=-1$ and $f'(c_1)=2$, there must be a $c\in(c_1,c_2)\subset(0,2)$ such that $f'(c)=-1/2$.

Comment: @zhw.: the OP's arguments don't show $f'(0)=2$ and $f'(2)=-1$, so it's not as simple as that.

Comment: @Perspicuity: besides your real question, you've made a typo; your second application of the MVT should begin with $f(2)-f(1)$, not $f(2)-f(0)$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Yes, you're right. I stopped reading after $c_1,c_2$ were found. Not sure why $f'(0),f'(2)$ were even mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you don't have enough information to determine $f'(0)$ and $f'(2)$ (which would have to be one-sided derivatives, at best). So you're wrong to claim $-1/2$ is between $f'(0)$ and $f'(2)$.

But this is no problem; you can do even better. You know $f'(c_2)<f'(c_1)$ and $k$ is between these two values; you also know $0<c_1<1<c_2<2$. So there is a $c$ in $(c_1,c_2)$ such that $f'(c)=k$. But if $c\in(c_1,c_2)$, then $c\in(0,2)$, because $(c_1,c_2)\subset(0,2)$.

Comment: The claim "You know $f'(c_2)<f'(c_1)$ and $k$ is between these two values; you also know $0<c_1<1<c_2<2$. So there is a $c$ in $(c_1,c_2)$ such that $f′(c)=k$" is precisely the non trivial part of the problem and the Theorem in my answer solve!!

Comment: @sinbadh: no, the OP seems to know what Darboux's theorem says. he/she is not asking for a statement or proof of that theorem but whether the claim that $k$ is between $f'(0)$ and $f'(2)$ is valid. that is the question.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem: If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is diferentiable, and $f^\prime(a)<f^\prime(b)$ ($f^\prime(b)<f^\prime(a)$), then, for each $c\in (f^\prime(a),f^\prime(b))$ ($c\in (f^\prime(b),f^\prime(a))$) there is a $\xi\in(a,b)$ such that $f^\prime(\xi)=c$ (that is $f^\prime$ satisfies the conclusion of IVT althought $f^\prime$ is not continuos)

Proof: http://web02.gonzaga.edu/faculty/axon/Larson_problem-solving.pdf, page 207 of the book.

[image]

Now, you can do it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @symplectomorphic You have $f^\prime(c_1)=2$ and $f^\prime(c_2)=-1$.  Then, for $-1/2\in(-1,2)$, by the theorem there is $\xi\in(c_1,c_2)\subseteq[0,2]$ such that $f^\prime(\xi)=-1/2$.

Comment: I'm aware; that's what my answer says. But your post just states Darboux's theorem. The OP did not ask what this theorem says.

Comment: I'm putting Darboux theorem in my answer. Where is the error?

Comment: you misunderstand. it's not that you are making an error (indeed, you aren't); it's that you *are not answering the OP's question*, which says: "My problem is with claiming that $k=−1/2$ is between $f′(0)$ and $f′(2)$. I am not sure if this necessarily follows from the previous result. [...] Is there any way I could fix/improve my proof, or is it fine as is?"